# How include variables in SetBody using $_GET in php

Tags: php

hi how can i include variables in SetBody using $_GET in php. Now i have:

```
<?php

$name =$_GET["name"];
echo $name;
$request->setBody('{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.create",
    "params": {
        "host": $nam,
        "interfaces": [
            {
                "type": 2,
                "main": 1,
                "useip": 1,
                "ip": $name,
                "dns": "",
                "port": "161",
                "details": {
                    "version": 3,
                    "bulk": 0,
                    "securityname": "mysecurityname",
                    "contextname": "",

?>
```

i need to get name from url. i am usinfg API to zabbix with http_Request2. Thanks for support.
My request looks like : https://localhost/zabbix.php?name=1.1.1.1
Output is:

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "error":{
        "code":-32700,
        "message":"Parse error",
        "data":"Invalid JSON. An error occurred on the server while parsing the JSON text."
        },
    "id":null
}
```

I tried  using $variablename but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a single quoted string literal you will have to stop the literal, concatenate the value and then restart the literal.

```
$name =$_GET["name"];
echo $name;
$request->setBody('{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.create",
    "params": {
        "host": "' . $name . '",        // see here
        "interfaces": [
            {
                "type": 2,
                "main": 1,
                "useip": 1,
                "ip": "' . $name . '",  // and here
                "dns": "",
                "port": "161",
                "details": {
                    "version": 3,
                    "bulk": 0,
                    "securityname": "mysecurityname",
                    "contextname": "",
```